# How to add a working navigation mesh and path finding to a maze in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine

I have generated a maze:

Top view in wireframe:

[image: [Top view in wireframe]]

Solid view:

[image: [Solid view]]

For a game I'm making, I need the enemy to follow the player around the maze, but when I try to generate a navigation mesh, nothing happens. (It says theres a Navmesh, but it doesn't seem to be made.

Comment: share the blend file through http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @Lev Ok: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36502

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is not recognized by blender.It pops an error.
It seems like it was corrupted.

I tried changing it by deleting all the top vertices(there are also 4 vertices I think a bit missplaced) but even with the basic scaled plane, the same error pops.

I created a new plane in your file and it worked just fine. I don't know if it is fixable without remaking it from scratch though.

This guy here disagrees: [same error](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-288720.html)

Comment: Could it be corrupted because I generated it with a python script? @Lev

Comment: I haven't done this to know. But in the blender artist's archive a guy mention the use of an add-on might cause this. And add-ons are like scripts so it could be possible that a script has messed it some how. Start a new blend file, run the script again. Try to generate the mesh. If it fails again, then it could be it.